# node.js put event right after another event

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

Let's say I have two async events, both need to i/o with remote exchange.

```
placeOrder()
cancelOrder()
```

Both events fire in async way, which means cancelOrder can be called before placeOrder return. Tricky part is I need the placeOrder to return an Order ID first otherwise there is no way to call cancelOrder, so I need some way to block the cancelOrder event right until placeOrder returns, and the blockage cannot be too long otherwise the Order may be executed, so loop/timeout/frequent checking doesn't work here.

Any idea?

Comment: Do these functions return promises? Accept callbacks? Where did they come from? Did you write them yourself or are they part of a library?

Comment: Promises? Callbacks?

Comment: In house code, so we can change to use promise or callback.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a Promise for that. If your functions already return a promise, you can simply chain the both functions using `then()`

```
placeOrder().then(val => cancelOrder(val));
```

If they do not, you can put them inside a `new Promise`

```js
function foo() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // do stuff
    resolve('<result of placeOrder here>');
  });
}

function bar(val) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    // do stuff
    resolve('whatever')
  })
}


and call 

foo()
  .then(value => bar(value))
  .then(console.log);
```

Comment: Thanks. I have thought about this solution, but I cannot chain them together since placeOrder doesn't necessarily follow by a cancelOrder. cancelOrder can never fire. I can add a flag to check so every time I place an order then when returned I check if this order need to be canceled, if yes then I cancel, but by doing this, the code will be very trivial/talktive.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to use ES2017, the you can use `async` functions. For example, I'm going to assume that your functions perform some sort of request to the database using `fetch` or `axios` since you haven't specified. Then you can write `placeOrder` and `cancelOrder` like so:

```
const placeOrder = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('/place_order');

        // Do something with the response
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle error
    }
};

const cancelOrder = async () => {
    try {
        const response = await fetch('/cancel_order');

        // Do something with the response
    } catch (err) {
        // Handle error
    }
};

const someFunction = async () => {
    await placeOrder();
    await cancelOrder();
};
```